# Verifying if image file exist

Tags: testing

I have to verify if an image file exist in website.  However, when the certain URL cannot search for the image file, the site would quickly re-direct to prompt "imagenotfound.png" file making me difficult to get any macro code correctly prompt the image cannot be found, especially that imagenotfound.png file is already prompt up.  Not sure if anyone can help?  I am new to write macro.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In which language?

You could use javascript for example:

```
function checkIfimageExists(imageurl){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', imageurl, false);

    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;

}
```

Comment: It's excel macro. if the image is not found, I will add a comment to one of the excel cell saying, "image do not exist".

Comment: Check out this: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/639463-check-if-url-exists.html - and add "Excel" to your tags (so the users can see which language is prefered)

Comment: Thanks - that code doesn't work and hence I tried some other sources.  Not sure if you could help?